# Python - Convert CSV to JSON based on headers dynamically

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am trying to convert a python dataframe to Json. Below is my csv format

```
policyID|Name | Description | Contact_Telephone | Contact_Email |
--------|-----| ------------|-------------------|---------------|
1221    |ABC  | New Policy  | 1234567890        | abc@mail.com  |
1223    |DEF  | Old Policy  | 2341243324        | def@gmail.com |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Expected output in JSON is:

```
{
    "policyID": 1221,
    "Name": "ABC",
    "Description": "New Policy",
    "Contact": 
    {
        "Telephone": 1234567890,
        "Email": abc@mail.com        
    },
    "policyID": 1223,
    "Name": "DEF",
    "Description": "Old Policy",
    "Contact": 
    {
        "Telephone": 2341243324,
        "Email": def@gmail.com        
    }
}
```

So basically, I need to look into the columns and if the column name has _ i need to consider it as a next level of json with nesting. I was able to convert the first level elements from dataframe into the JSON using pandas `to_json` merthod and `orient=records` which seemed straight forward. Could you please help me on how can this be handled to form a nested json whenever we encounter an _ in the column name

Comment: Your JSON result should be a JSON array with 2 items : one for each policy.

Comment: Not sure that using `pandas` is the easiest way to do it.
Working with dicts looks easier. When you get the desired nesting, converting the dict to json is immediate. Have a look at the `csv` module and its `DictReader` class.

Answer (score 0):

First get  all columns names without `_` to `MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), split columns names by `_` to `MultiIndex in columns` and create dictionaries by convert all groups to dictionaries by [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) with `Series` constructor, last convert `df1` to final dictionary:

```
print (df)
   policyID Name Description  Contact_Telephone  Contact_Email Info_Text  \
0      1221  ABC  New Policy         1234567890   abc@mail.com         a   
1      1223  DEF  Old Policy         2341243324  def@gmail.com         b   

     Info_Email  
0  def@mail.com  
1  erc@mail.com
```

---

```
cols = [x for x in df.columns if '_' not in x]

df1 = df.set_index(cols1)
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)

def f(x):
    first = x.columns[0][0]
    s = x.droplevel(axis=1, level=0).to_dict('records')
    return pd.Series(s, name=first, index=x.index)

df1 = df1.groupby(level=0, axis=1).apply(f).reset_index()
print (df1)
   policyID Name Description  \
0      1221  ABC  New Policy   
1      1223  DEF  Old Policy   

                                             Contact  \
0  {'Telephone': 1234567890, 'Email': 'abc@mail.c...   
1  {'Telephone': 2341243324, 'Email': 'def@gmail....   

                                     Info  
0  {'Text': 'a', 'Email': 'def@mail.com'}  
1  {'Text': 'b', 'Email': 'erc@mail.com'}
```

---

```
d = df1.to_dict('records')
print (d)
[{'policyID': 1221, 
  'Name': 'ABC',
  'Description': 'New Policy',
  'Contact': {'Telephone': 1234567890, 'Email': 'abc@mail.com'}, 
  'Info': {'Text': 'a', 'Email': 'def@mail.com'}}, 
 {'policyID': 1223,
  'Name': 'DEF', 
  'Description': 'Old Policy', 
  'Contact': {'Telephone': 2341243324,
              'Email': 'def@gmail.com'},
  'Info': {'Text': 'b', 'Email': 'erc@mail.com'}}]
```

If need `json`:

```
import json

j = json.dumps(d)
```